# Bash Built-in Regular Expression Usage

Tags: bash, regular-expression

I've tried to find all line's which begin with at least 1 tab.
Several Variations didn't work out.
The most Basic one:

```
#!/bin/bash

FILE=emptiness
{ while IFS=""; read line
do
regex='^[\t]+'
if [[ $line =~ $regex ]]; then
        echo "line with pattern found"
else
        echo "pattern not found"
fi

done

}< $FILE
```

Does anybody know whether it is even possible to find Tabs with the built in comparison function or how do it?

My Version is 4.1.2

Comment: In addition to the answer by @choroba, change the `while` line like this: `while IFS="" read -r line; do`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to include the tab literally into the regex. You can use the `$''` quotes for that:

```
regex=$'^\t+'
```